# AT&T Assembly not return with exit 1

Tags: assembly, error-handling, x86, return, exit

I've read the documentation on assembly and this is how you exit a program using the AT&T Syntax

```
.section .text
  .global _start
_start:
  mov $60, %eax      # System call number for exit
  mov $1, %edi       # Load the exit status code (1 for error)
  syscall            # Invoke the exit system call
```

The problem is that it's supposed to exit with a value of 1, but when I type "as -o main.o exit.s && ld -o main main.o", it exits with a value of 0. But for some reason when using a Makefile file and writing the exact same thing (plus ./main), it exits with a value of 1.

Comment: You did run it with `./main` after the first command as well, right? Otherwise you are just checking the exit code of `ld` which is hopefully zero.